# Why do my new ik rigs twitch after the 2.9 update?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints, error

I'm not sure if people had similar issues and asked a question similar to this, or if its just me, but after the new 2.9 update, any new ik rigs I make don't act properly Instead they start to twitch uncontrollably.I have unparented the ik controller, disabled snapping , and all the other things that would cause ik rigs to lose control. So is there a way to fix this?, or is this just a bug that happens?

Comment: Hello, could you make and share a very simple exemple so that we can test? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Yeah, here's the .blend file (I'm not sure if its a bug, or if i'm going crazy) https://pasteall.org/blend/aaaa43fff29d4d1e9bad92dba2f5e71d

Comment: in the file you share, Bone.003 is parented to 002, it should not

Comment: I unparented the bone, which fixed it!, i guess i just forgot how to rig

Comment: ok, great then  ;)